# Unable to click signature field in PDF, but works after opening on Adobe Acrobat Reader & Saving

Tags: pdf, adobe, ghostscript, acrobat, postscript

I have a pdf file ( I think it's generated or combined using pdftk, not sure).

Which is uploaded to a e-signing saas service where the customer clicks on the signature field in the pdf and the third party api let customers sign.

However, **the pdf's signature field isn't clickable, until I open it in Acrobat reader and save.**

I tried using ghostscript but with no success. Any idea how I can make my pdf detect signature fields?

Comment: Apparently there is an error in your pdf file. If you want help, therefore, you should share that pdf file.

Comment: @mkl The only pdf I have is the sensitive one

Comment: @mkl any suggestions on how I can look at these errors?

Comment: Essentially by taking the pdf specification and checking in which way your pdf is not correct. That's what I'd have done if you'd shared the pdf.

Comment: @mkl where can I find the specification?

Comment: Google for pdf32000. You should find a pdf on the Adobe site that contains a copy of ISO 32000-1 with merely the ISO headers missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in my case.

**Note:** I had also tried using ghostscript, hexapdf, mutool,...
Also, the below answer was a source of inspiration in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344208/5647479

**Solution:**

```
pdftk contract.pdf cat output works.pdf
```

And to see the fields after running the command:

```
pdftk works.pdf dump_data_fields_utf8
```

Works on both pdftk and pdftk-java, you can find the docs for this command in the pdftk documentation burried deep.

**Aside:** Had to do a lot of reading to solve this, and reading adobe specifications and other docs wouldn't be a great idea as there's no end to it.